# How to load an external CSS file into the HTML with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to load a html file which contains styling aswell. Can I load a html file which contains styling?

Update: The style is loaded via an external CSS file

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: Embedded CSS sure, style references with CDNs would also work. Why not try it out by going to the route and see for yourself. Not sure if u are asking for external local CSS files?

Comment: @ambianBeing i have loaded the index.html file it has external css linked to it.But only the html part shows up.No styling appears..

Comment: In that case, please refer the answer I have posted and check it out if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load it. HTML that [contains or links to CSS](http://www.boogiejack.com/CSS_2.html), is still valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To load an external CSS file, you can serve them as static files with express [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) and then reference it into the HTML file.

For example: Assume this directory structure, serve the `public` folder

```
|---node_modules 
|---index.html 
|---package.json
|---package-lock.json 
|---server.js
|---public  
    |---images 
    |---js 
    |---css
        |--style.css
```

server.js

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/index.html"));
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>This is index.html</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```